# How to solve SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my MySQL error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 2
```

I googled it and read something about it, bud I couldn't understand.

How to solve it?

This is the main piece of `addStudent.php`:

```
require_once('../db.php');
$db = new DB();
if (isset($_POST['st_fname']) && isset($_POST['st_lname']) && isset($_POST['st_class']) && isset($_POST['st_grade']))
{
    $db->addStudent($_POST["st_fname"], $_POST["st_lname"], $_POST["st_class"], $_POST["st_grade"], $_POST["checkOlamp"]);
}
```

and this is a part of `db.php`:

```
public function addStudent($fname, $lname, $classnum, $grade, $olamp)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO t_student (s_fname, s_lname, s_class, s_grade, s_olamp) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$classnum', '$grade', '$olamp');";
    $this->execute($query);
}
```

And the t_student has a filed as `primary` key which is auto increment.

- db.php is something that I always use it instead of mysql_connection function in php, but I don't know what it is exactly. I know something that called "PDO" is used there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the values of some column in your table must be unique, and you are trying to insert a duplicate row.

BTW, your function is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should always escape your data before including it in a SQL query.

Comment: I found the problem! Thanks!
+ I heard that php5 prevent sql injection, but how can someone inject some "bad" thing here?(I use isset for better result) Only a person whose `if ($_SESSION['adm'] === true)` have access to this page. So what's the risk?

Comment: It's still very bad practices; If someone breaks in your admin area, he can also run anything on your SQL server.

Comment: And since addStudent.php is vulnerable to CSRF, everyone can trick your own browser into calling the script with any parameter he wants. No need to have 'adm'=true.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to solve "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry" is to pass the values in the input fields of form like this:
you can see value before placeholder...
note:articles is the DB table name

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputTitle">Title</label>
      <input type="title" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" 
      aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
      value="<?php echo $articles->title;?>"placeholder="Enter title">
      <small id="titleHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
```